# Passing string through unwind segue and/or dismissViewController SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

VC1 has 1 button **F1** which >segues> to VC2 which has 2 buttons **Qd** and **Qs**

**Qd** is connected to dismissViewController

**Qs** is connected to unwindSegue

**My Objective**: learn to change **F1**'s image to "Qd" image through dismissViewController, and learn to change **F1**'s image to "Qs" image through unwindSegue.

**Question1**: Why is **Qd**(VC2) NOT setting F1String(VC1) = F1Card(VC2)?

**Question2**: How do I apply this to unwindSegue for **Qs**?

VC1 (Table)

```
import UIKit

class Table: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var F1: UIButton!
var F1String:String = "Default"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let F1Image = UIImage(named: "\(F1String)") as UIImage!
    F1.setImage(F1Image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

@IBAction func unwindFromFlop(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
}
```

VC2 (FlopPop)

```
import UIKit

class FlopPop: UIViewController {
var F1Card = String()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DVC : Table = segue.destinationViewController as Table
    DVC.F1String = F1Card
}
@IBAction func Qd(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let F1Card = "Qd"
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

THANKS DDD

Answer (score 0):

This solved the unwind part

VC1

```
import UIKit

class Table: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var F1: UIButton!
var message : NSString = "Default"

@IBAction func unwindFromFlop(unwindSegue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let F1Image = UIImage(named: "\(message)") as UIImage!
    F1.setImage(F1Image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    checkLabel.text = message
}
}
```

VC2

```
import UIKit

class FlopPop: UIViewController {
var F1Card = String()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    F1Card = segue.identifier!

    let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as Table
    DVC.message = F1Card

}
}
```

I think it had to do with using NSString to pass the data instead of just a string.

If anyone can help to explain why this is I'd greatly appreciate it and  I'm still hoping to learn the work around for dismissViewController.